# Error processing xml documents

Tags: sql-server, xml, xml-parsing

we loaded few xml docs from filessystem to sql server into 'xml' datatype column.

when running `select * from table` we are facing below error for one of the file

```
"An error occurred while executing batch. Error message is: Lists of BinaryXml value tokens not supported."
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ssolved my issue

```
SELECT CONVERT(XML, CONVERT(nvarchar(max), XMLData)) xmldata,name from  Table
```